# How to open a python script from flask-python script

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I would like to call a function from a external python script which is in the same folder as of the flask python script.When the server is loaded,I would like to initiate the "testfunc of QEFtest.py file when the button is pressed on the html page.Could anyone help me in this issue I tried doing it in few ways,but it did not work.

```
import flask,flask.views
import functools
import spirentQEF
import subprocess
import sys 

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "bacon"

users ={'jake':'bacon','root':'root'}
class Main(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('index.html')

    def post(self):
        if 'logout' in flask.request.form:
            flask.session.pop('username', None)
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
        required = ['username', 'passwd']
        for r in required:
            if r not in flask.request.form:
                flask.flash("Error: {0} is required.".format(r))
                return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
        username = flask.request.form['username']
        passwd = flask.request.form['passwd']
        print('username  %s'%username)
        print('passwd %s' %passwd)
        if username in users and users[username] == passwd:
            flask.session['username'] = username
#             print('username %s'%username)
#             print('passwd %s' %passwd)
        else:
            flask.flash("Invalid Username or incorrect Password")
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
                
def login_required(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in flask.session:
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flask.flash("You need to login to visit this link ! ")
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
    return wrapper
```

**# Code for the remote html page**

```
class Remote(flask.views.MethodView):
    @login_required
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('remote.html')
#         proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"QEFtest.py"])
#         proc.communicate()

    @login_required     
    def post(self):
        result = str(flask.request.form['expression'])
        flask.flash("The Modcod which is is being tested : ")
        flask.flash(result)
        flask.flash("Test is running, and we are  in the middle of testing one MODCOD. Please check back later")
        print('result :  %s' %result)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('remote'))
        return subprocess.call()
        print('result  :  %s' %result)
        print("its working")
```

## I would like to initiate the QEFtestfunc.py over here when the button is clicked

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,"QEFtest.py"])
proc.communicate()


class page(flask.views.MethodView):
    @login_required
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('third.html')

    @login_required
    def post(self):
        res = str(flask.request.form['expression'])
        flask.flash("The modcod which is being tested :")
        flask.flash(res)
        flask.flash("The test is in the final stage please wait for few minutes")
        print('result : %s' %res)
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('page'))
        print('result :  %s' %res)

x = QEFtest.testFunc(999,
              9,
              0.9,
              100000000,
              60.0,
              0.0,
             0.1,
             "10.169.6.74",
              3,
              3,
             1,
              2,
              str("C:/testdir/webservertest"))
app.add_url_rule('/',view_func=Main.as_view('index'),methods=['GET', 'POST'])
print("one")
print(str(__name__))
app.add_url_rule('/remote/',view_func=Remote.as_view('remote'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.add_url_rule('/page/',view_func=page.as_view('page'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
print("two")
app.debug = True
print("three")
app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print("its working")
    x = QEFtest.testFunc(999,
              9,
              0.9,
              100000000,
              60.0,
              0.0,
             0.1,
             "10.169.6.74",
              3,
              3,
             1,
              2,
              str("C:/testdir/webservertest"))
#return str(flask.request.form['expression'])
```

I am not understanding how to initiate the function of another python file when the server is running.The function does few calculations when the button is clicked.